# Javascript - why its not possible to make function inside for look synchronous using async/await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Im sorry for the question since there are already many similar questions. However, I still dont understand. The code below is suppose to show HOW to make a for loop act synchronous. However, as I see it its still not snychronous.
The output of the code below is
**
1
2
3
after forEach
done
**

But I wonder, if we put the await keyword in front of the function, why is the output not:

**
1
after forEach
2
after forEach
3
after forEach
done
**

? Because result holds one num at a time, waiting for the execution of returnNum.

```js
const asyncFunction = async () => {
  const nums = [1, 2, 3];

  for (const num of nums) {
    const result = await returnAsyncNum(num);
    console.log(result);
  }

  console.log('after forEach');
}

const returnAsyncNum = x => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500, x));
}

asyncFunction().then(() => {
  console.log('done');
})
```

Comment: `console.log('after forEach');` is executed just once, regardless of synchronous or asynchronous execution. I don't really see why you would you expect it to run three times. Moreover, I don't really see why you say it does not look synchronous. The execution is *not* synchronous but `await` does make it behave like it is. And the output you get is consistent with what synchronous code would produce.

Comment: yes sorry, thats true and I do not know anymore why I was expecting it to run 3 times

Answer (score 1):

The console.log('after forEach') will only execute once the for is fully completed. That does makes sense since you are letting it after the for of, doesn't it?

If you put a console.log before the resolve(x), you will see how the code is waiting for the promise to return the number.

Answer (score 1):

That's point of `async functions`, they allow you to write async code as if it were sync.
You are waiting for the promise to complete and get its value.
Since you are waiting for the `Promise`, the execution of the async function stops in the `await` and when the `Promise` fulfills you get its value and the execution continues.

Also your expected output does not make any sense, `console.log('after forEach')` can only log once by calling the function once.